# Securing elasticsearch behind a reverse proxy

Tags: webserver, proxy

I intend to run an Elasticsearch index to store a persistent copy of data retrieved from an external service. My plan is to host the Elasticsearch index on AWS, and have it listen on `127.0.0.1` only. I was then intending to use a reverse proxy (**nginx**) to only allow search-type requests, and reject any others (e.g., updates, cluster management/stats, etc).

As I understand it, I could then do all updates locally on the box itself, and the reverse proxy would be enough security to prevent someone stomping all over my data.

**So, my question is this**: would a simple reverse proxy allowing/denying access based on **URI** be secure? What problems could I face with regards to malicious editing of data? Are there attack vectors on such a setup that I have not considered?

Note: I intend to tighten the firewall to only allow access to the proxy port, etc. The focus of this question is on the security of the reverse-proxy idea!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Elasticsearch, but what kind of reverse proxy are you using? Is it something you're making / defining yourself?

Comment: I was planning to use Nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse proxy is one way to do it.  There are some other plugins that you could put on your elasticsearch cluster that are a bit more robust:

1. [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/introduction.html) - Commercial license only, elastic.co

   > Shield is a plugin for Elasticsearch that enables you to easily secure
   >   a cluster. With Shield, you can password-protect your data as well as
   >   implement more advanced security measures such as encrypting
   >   communications, role-based access control, IP filtering, and auditing.
   >   This guide describes how to install Shield, configure the security
   >   features you need, and interact with your secured cluster.
2. [SearchGuard](http://floragunn.com/searchguard/) - Commercial and Free licenses, from floragunn

   > Search Guard offers the same functionality as Shield, adds additional
   >   features on top, at a much lower price point and with a more flexible
   >   licensing schema. Additional features include:
   >
   > OpenSSL support Kerberos support HTTP Proxy Authentication support
   >   JSON Web token support Source code available – run your own security
   >   audits Licenses for Search Guard are based on production clusters, not
   >   nodes. That means that you can scale your cluster up- and down as
   >   necessary, without affecting the license costs. Development-,
   >   staging-, integration- and QA/AUT-systems are covered by the license
   >   as well at no additional cost.